# Relationship from multiple table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am having ModelNos table which contain reference to manufacturer table and series table 
Can you tell me how to define relationship in ModelNos table so that I can retrive manufacturer and
series data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have these eloquent models: `ModelNo`, `Manufacturer` and `Series`

```
class ModelNo extends Eloquent {

    function manufacturer(){
        return $this->hasMany('Manufacturer');
    }

    function series(){
        return $this->hasMany('Series');
    }

}

class Manufacturer extends Eloquent {

    function modelNo(){
        return $this->belongsTo('ModelNo');
    }

}

class Series extends Eloquent {

    function modelNo(){
        return $this->belongsTo('ModelNo');
    }

}
```

then, if you want get all the `ModelNos`, you can use:

```
$modelnos = ModelNo::all();
```

and to print them:

```
foreach($modelnos as $modelno){

    // assuming both have an 'id' field
    echo $modelno->manufacturer->id; 
    echo $modelno->series->id;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships).

You should use `belongsTo($className)` for a `ModelNo` to map a certain Manufacturer, or `hasMany($className)` as pointed above if it's a collection.